# Assign multilayer array output to individual variables

Tags: php

I am recovering an array from a CSV and getting values like this after i iterate through them with a while loop:

```
  (a)  Array ( [0] => VAL11
         [1] => VAL12
         [2] => VAL13
         [3] => VAL14
         [4] => VAL15 ) 

  (b)  Array ( [0] => VAL21
         [1] => VAL22
         [2] => VAL23
         [3] => VAL24
         [4] => VAL25 )
```

How would I go about extracting only Array (b) into its own new array?

The problem is that the identifiers of all the arrays are the same, based only on numeric keys

Thanks

Comment: How did you iterate? could you show us code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array(array('VAL11','VAL12','VAL13','VAL14','VAL15'),array('VAL21','VAL22','VAL23','VAL24','VAL25'));

$newarr = $array[1]; 
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => VAL21
    [1] => VAL22
    [2] => VAL23
    [3] => VAL24
    [4] => VAL25
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if I understood you at all, but:

```
$b = $data['b'];
```